# How to save a user's role history

Tags: discord, discord.js

Is there any way to properly save a user's role history without the need for a database and/or a JSON file on Discord.js? I would like to create a function that logs the roles a user has at the beginning of the command and gives them back after a specific function is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to save a user's Role history on Discord without the need for a Database and/or any JSON file, you must add a few lines to your code in order to do this.

You first need to make sure your Discord bot has "Privileged Gateway Intents" enabled within the Discord Developer Portal panel, this will highly improve the accuracy of the bot's cache fetching tasks. Next, create a constant for the user mention or user ID, just like the following:

```
const saveRolesFor = (message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]));
```

With these 2 arguments, you will be able to state the id of the user or mention the user instead.

Then you must save the roles for the specified user inside another constant variable, just like the following:

```
const roleHistory = saveRolesFor.roles.cache.map(r => r.id);
```

The reason why mapping the roles is the best thing to do is due to the roles cache containing other elements, aside from the actual user roles, mapping them would simply include the actual roles of the user, preventing potential issues.

Now you must state the new role you'd like the user to have, just like the following:

```
let roleToAdd = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Role');
```

Time to remove all of the previous roles and add the `roleToAdd` to the user, you should do it as:

```
await(saveRolesFor.roles.set([roleToAdd.id]));
```

You will want to `set` the user's roles, as this function automatically removes any other role the user had, and add the single role you have stated, you no longer require the `.remove` and `.add` functions.

After these functions have been performed, you can be creative and add the rolehistory back after certain functions are completed.
A very simple example of this would be to add the roles back to the user once a message is sent, for example:

```
message.channel.send(`The roles for ${saveRolesFor} have been added back!`)
.then(saveRolesFor.roles.set(roleHistory));
```

All of the user's previous roles will be added successfully, and the `roleToAdd` will be removed, as you `.set` the roleHistory of the user, meaning you added those specific roles only. The `.then` function is calling the `roleHistory set` after the message is sent to the channel, you could modify it to properly fit into what you attempt to obtain out of your code.

This won't be the best way to add the roles back, as it will take less than a second, but the functions shown above will be highly useful at the time of creating a similar command.

Hope it was helpful!

Comment: What about when the client restarts?

Comment: That is the downside of the roleHistory function through a simple command line, that's just the basic idea for it, as you are not storing any value in any database, meaning once the bot re-starts, the function will not give the roles back, this is due to the bot saving the roles for the specified user right after you type the command. In order to save the roles and apply them even after the bot re-starts, you would require a database to store them, and then fetch them with a different command.

Comment: Would work for a small-scale bot on a reliable VPS, however not so much for a large-scale bot that would be getting constant updates